# O que fazer com perguntas em um outro idioma?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, idioma

Quando isso ocorre no StackOverflow (e acredito que em outros sites em inglês da rede), perguntas em um idioma diferente devem ser sinalizadas para um moderador, [segundo o MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94657/177950). Devemos ter a mesma política aqui?

Hoje foi feita [uma pergunta em inglês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8666/215) aqui no SOPT, e procedi dessa fora (sinalizei, comentando que deveria ser migrada para o SOEN). Porém surgiu a dúvida se essa era mesmo a ação correta, se a pergunta deveria ter sido traduzida para o português, ou se cabia alguma outra ação. O usuário era novo, e não havia nenhuma indicação de que era sua intenção participar da comunidade em português.

Devemos ter uma nova opção de migração em `Encerrando > Descontextualizado > Migração`? Sempre me incomodou o fato de que essa opção apenas dá uma lista finita de sites, sem a opção `Outro`. Mas isso parece [ir contra a vontade do SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96205/177950), então não vou insistir... Só penso que talvez seria interessante criar uma opção pro SOEN, se isso se tornar comum (parece que já ocorreu antes) e for facilitar o trabalho de migração.

Por ora, o que fazer nessa situação?

Comment: Um cidadão (neste caso, um [Dinamarquês](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6376/devcorominas)) que não consegue ver a diferença entre ***`Faça uma pergunta`*** e **`Ask a question`**, provavelmente é tão desorientado que a pergunta será *off-topic* no [so]. Essa [pergunta específica](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8666/creating-a-qrcode-creator-and-decoder-webapp) poderia ter 3 razões de fechamento lá: *too broad, unclear, recommendation*.

Comment: Acabou de acontecer algo parecido agora. Quando percebemos que o usuário pretende participar da comunidade SOPT e de forma errônea fez a pergunta em inglês, é válido efetuar a tradução?

Comment: @Ricardo Nesse caso, está óbvio que o OP fala português (a captura de tela mostra um sistema com termos em portugês). Se alguém **se dispor** a traduzir, não vejo problema, mas ninguém tem a **obrigação** de fazê-lo. Talvez a forma de proceder seja um pouco diferente também - tentar migrar pro SOEN num caso desses não seria a ação correta. Mas votar para fechar está ok também. Esta é minha opinião.

Comment: @Ricardo O que eu mais fiquei de cara com [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8753/3117) é que ela conseguiu dois votos a favor, agora a pouco que recebeu seu primeiro voto contra. Como podem votar a favor de uma pergunta que está em outra lingua??

Comment: @Math Foi exatamente essa pergunta que originou minha dúvida.

Comment: @Ricardo Sim, eu imaginei, por isso eu linkei ela. Agora tá +2/-2.

Comment: Bom, aparentemente é alguém de Minas Gerais perdido na Dinamarca. Mas [concorre ao prêmio *Sem Noção 2014*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8811/201).

Comment: @brasofilo Essa questão da interface de usuário é um problema comum. Conforme [discutido no MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62939/177950), se uma pessoa visita o SOEN com a tradução automática do Chrome ligada, ela pode ver um site em português - e achar que o site **é** em português (i.e. não estar ciente que uma tradução automática aconteceu). Imagino que o mesmo pode acontecer aqui, mas com tradução automática pro inglês (usuários no exterior por exemplo). Dessa forma, é bem possível que esse (e outros) usuário - do ponto de vista dele - tenha de fato lido `Ask a question` nesse site.

Comment: Hoje eu acho que essas perguntas deveriam ser fechadas com um motivo específico, e postei um pedido de sugestões aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513/sugest%C3%B5es-de-frase-pronta-para-fechamento-de-perguntas-em-outros-idiomas

Comment: Não seria mais fácil impedir que o `Faça uma pergunta` seja traduzido para `Ask a question`? Quero dizer, por que diabos o navegador traduz os botões? Se é SOpt, não tem que traduzir, pelo menos não o site, apenas os posts.

Comment: @Patrick Mas como isso seria feito? Usando uma imagem em vez de texto? Usando algo como a classe `notranslate`, e torcendo para o browser honrá-la? (Eu seria a favor de ambas alternativas, aliás...) [Esse problema é comum nos sites de língua inglesa](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62939/177950), e não parece ter solução fácil no caso geral. Mas em [casos específicos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165687/177950) (como esse que você sugeriu), concordo que seria uma opção viável. Só não sei se seria suficiente pro usuário "se tocar".

Comment: Eu também pensei em usar imagem, mas isso provavelmente daria um trabalho imenso, mas concordo que o `notranslate` seria uma melhor opção.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sobre adicionar uma opção de migração, eu falei sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1253/12):

> É uma ideia que faz sentido, mas que eu não estou 100% confiante de
>   que daria certo. Existe uma única regra básica, no que diz respeito a
>   migrações:
>
> > Não migre porcaria
>
> Então, partindo do SOPT, teríamos dois requisitos para migrar algo
>   para o SO:
>
> 1. Estar em Inglês
> 2. Não ser porcaria
>
> O problema é que ninguém obrigado a saber Inglês para participar do
>   SOPT, e isso influencia ambos os requisitos. Quem não sabe Inglês não
>   pode ter **certeza** de que um texto em não-Português está realmente
>   em Inglês e, da mesma forma, pode ter ainda menos certeza de que não é
>   porcaria.
>
> Então, considerando que o mesmo equívico pode, tranquilamente, ser
>   cometido por 5 pessoas (principalmente porque o voto do primeiro
>   influencia o resto) talvez seja melhor deixar a migração para o SOEN
>   apenas nas mãos dos moderadores. Obviamente, também não é requisito
>   que moderadores saibam inglês mas é desejável e, se necessário, podem
>   vir até mim mais facilmente.

Quanto ao que fazer, ao invés de migrar, marcar para atenção dos moderadores é o suficiente. Além disso, fazer os comentários pedindo a tradução é uma boa ideia. A pergunta em Inglês pode realmente ter sido um equívoco, e o autor merece uma chance de corrigir o erro (como já aconteceu diversas vezes). Nesse caso nossos moderadores podem apenas desconsiderar a flag (como já aconteceu).

Não gosto muito da ideia de traduzirmos as perguntas nós mesmos, porque o autor pode não falar Português, e estaríamos nos apropriando do seu conteúdo sem que ele obtenha qualquer benefício, já que não conseguiria entender as respostas. Exceto para casos em que o autor é **comprovadamente** capaz de entender Português mas se recusa a traduzir o post. Nesse caso, traduzam à vontade! :)
(isso **também** já aconteceu)

Comment: Auahauha, +1 pelo "não migre procaria", mas voltando ao assunto... Não seria mais viável migrar tudo não apenas para o SOEN, mas também para todos os outros sites (uma dúvida sobre servidor pode ser redirecionada para o Server Fault) e lá eles checarem se é porcaria ou não? Afinal, lá eles não teriam o problema da barreira linguística na parte da avaliação. Caso seja porcaria, basta descartar.

Comment: @Patrick Isso seria jogar o problema pra outro lugar, às vezes até de forma indevida (como identificar pra **qual** site migrar uma pergunta, se não entendemos a pergunta?). Migrar tudo para o SOen, ou outros sites, seria ferir o primeiro princípio da migração: *Não migre porcaria*

Answer (score 5):

Minha resposta é baseada num exemplo prático, que aconteceu hoje:

- avise o autor da pergunta, através de comentário, que a pergunta deveria estar em português.

Mas eu não sei se esta é a resposta "certa" ou a ação recomendada.

No caso real em questão, o usuário, após ser alertado pelo meu comentário, [traduziu a questão para o português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14822/angularjs-ng-repeat-nao-esta-pegando-valores).

Na verdade, antes mesmo de realizar a ação de postar o comentário, eu vim aqui no **Meta** buscar orientação sobre o que fazer, e encontrei esta pergunta, sem resposta...

O "comentário alertando" que eu fiz até funcionou neste caso... mas eu também gostaria de saber sobre algum consenso a respeito do que fazer neste caso. Acrescento esta "resposta"/"sugestão" apenas para acender a discussão.