# Devemos ter opção de migração para o SOzão?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Ao me deparar com essa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13915/postgis-problem, imediatamente fui votar para fechar como "descontextualizada > pertence a outro site", mas a unica opçao era migrar para o Meta.

Entendo que isto foi feito pra não misturar línguas diferentes (mandar para o Arqade uma questão em português, por exemplo), mas por ser o mesmo assunto, creio que o SOzão deveria ser uma das alternativas, além do meta, visto que ja aconteceu mais de uma vez de perguntas em inglês serem postadas aqui.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É uma ideia que faz sentido, mas que eu não estou 100% confiante de que daria certo. Existe uma única regra básica, no que diz respeito a migrações:

> Não migre porcaria

Então, partindo do SOPT, teríamos dois requisitos para migrar algo para o SO:

1. Estar em Inglês
2. Não ser porcaria

O problema é que ninguém obrigado a saber Inglês para participar do SOPT, e isso influencia ambos os requisitos. Quem não sabe Inglês não pode ter **certeza** de que um texto em não-Português está realmente em Inglês e, da mesma forma, pode ter ainda menos certeza de que não é porcaria.

Então, considerando que o mesmo equívico pode, tranquilamente, ser cometido por 5 pessoas (principalmente porque o voto do primeiro influencia o resto) talvez seja melhor deixar a migração para o SOEN apenas nas mãos dos moderadores. Obviamente, também não é requisito que moderadores saibam inglês mas é desejável e, se necessário, podem vir até mim mais facilmente.

### EDIT

Conversando com o Zuul me toquei que podemos criar um motivo de descontextualização do tipo: "Não está em português". E utilizá-lo para as flags, ou até para fechar perguntas.

Flags seriam ideais, porque dessa foma chamariam a atenção dos moderadores, para talvez migrar a pergunta.

Comment: Quando dizes "_podem vir até mim mais facilmente_", estás a referir-te a levantar uma bandeira, certo?

Comment: **Hoje** a melhor maneira de chamar minha atenção é atravez de flags, sim. Quando tivermos moderadores, não vou mais tomar conta de todas as flags, mas moderadores tem outras maneiras de chamar a atenção dos CMs.

Comment: Ia jurar que tinha visto um VTC do género "descontextualizado porque está em Inglês" mas agora não estou a encontrar... ou só aparece em perguntas onde o sistema detecta texto em Inglês numa percentagem superior ao Português fora dos blocos de código e citações? De qualquer forma, a não existir, dá para criar algo desse género ou é preferível levantar a bandeira?

Comment: Adicionar um motivo extra para o off-topic é uma boa idéia. Vou emendar minha resposta.

Comment: Partindo do "não migre porcaria" realmente o enfoque muda bastante. Acho válidos todos os argumentos sobre os riscos, e realmente acho que já precisamos de mais moderadores, por esses e outros motivos. Quanto aos equivocos em série, esses realmente acontecem o tempo todo e nos mais variados assuntos, é provável que não seja diferente com a migração.

Answer (score 11):

Em casos excepcionais, como é o caso da pergunta que referiste e como já sucedeu no passado, penso que possa ser útil ter uma opção para sugerir a transferência para o SOEN.

**Por outro lado**, uma flag para um moderador será suficiente enquanto a vaga de cenários deste género é pequena, evitando assim que exista uso indevido da ferramenta:

[image: Captura de Tela]

No caso em particular da pergunta em questão, a mesma foi colocado no SOEN, pelo que no SOPT ou é traduzida ou fechada para ser eliminada automaticamente pelo sistema.

**Ver:** [postgis restoring backup from version 1.5 to 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23279022/352449)