# Como mover suas próprias perguntas de uma comunidade para outra?

Tags: suporte

Ao ser notificado que a minha pergunta é off-topic, é possível que o próprio o autor da pergunta mova ela para a comunidade correta? ou seria melhor esperar que algum administrador o faça?

Quais as opções possíveis?

1. Remover a pergunta e refazer na comunidade correta
2. Mover a pergunta para outra comunidade. (como fazer nesse caso?)
3. Esperar que ela seja [fechada]
4. Alguma outra alternativa

Comment: Não existe esse recurso, nesse caso o item 1 é o mais adequado. Migrar perguntas de um site para outro pode causar problemas para o migrado sem contar o idioma diferente.

Comment: Já Suspeitava não ser possível, só queria ter certeza =)

Comment: Relacionada: [Podemos ter opção de migração para o SOzão?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1241/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível para um usuário mover uma pergunta de um site para outro da rede. Acredito que se fosse possível, o fluxo de perguntas fora de escopo em cada site seria maior, devido a pessoas movendo perguntas livremente entre comunidades.

> Quais as opções possíveis?
>   Remover a pergunta e refazer na comunidade correta

Essa é geralmente a melhor opção. Dá menos trabalho aos demais usuários do site e mantém o site onde a pergunta é feita originalmente limpo.

> Mover a pergunta para outra comunidade. (como fazer nesse caso?)

Isso é uma funcionalidade que é habilitada de forma diferente em cada site. O SO em inglês, por exemplo, tem algumas opções pré-definidas para mover uma pergunta de um site para outro. As opções são relacionadas às perguntas que fogem de escopo com mais frequência, i.e.: pessoas que perguntam sobre admnistração de servidores no SO, quando deveriam perguntas no Server Fault.

Nesses casos, o fechamento é feito por moderador ou por pessoas que votam por fechar a questão por estar fora de escopo. A menos que o autor da pergunta seja um moderador, o máximo que ele pode fazer é votar pelo fechamento da própria pergunta, com o motivo de fuga de escopo, indicando o site correto no qual a pergunta deveria estar - se essa opção estiver disponível. Caso contrário, o melhor é apagar a pergunta.

Essa opção não está habilitada para o SO em português.

> Esperar que ela seja [fechada]

Se você sabe que a pergunta é inadequada, deixar que outras pessoas a fechem por você é deixar o seu trabalho nas mãos dos outros. Isso tende a se voltar contra o autor da pergunta.

> Alguma outra alternativa

A primeira alternativa é a mais rápida e sana.

Answer (score 3):

Você que sabe se quer ou não fazer sua pergunta em outra comunidade, isso é uma questão pessoal. Além disso, acredito que nenhum moderador nunca vai migrar uma publicação para outra comunidade, isso só é feito em casos de migração automática — que é uma das opções de fechamento.

Pra nós, a migração automática é impossível. Como somos a única comunidade lusófona da rede, não existe opção de migrar uma pergunta automaticamente para outro site (a não ser para o nosso meta, é claro).

Você é livre para fazer a pergunta em outro site, desde que respeite o escopo (e o idioma) dele.

Esperar a pergunta ser fechada não vai fazer diferença nenhuma.

Comment: No nosso contexto como você falou de fato não se aplica, mas e no caso da pergunta ser feita erradamente no SOen, a melhor opção é deletar a pergunta?

Comment: @JonathasB.C. Quem define as coisas no SOen é o pessoal de lá, eu não posso falar por eles porque não uso o SOen.

Comment: Eu acho que esperar a pergunta ser fechada é convite para votos negativos. Para usuários novatos e que já tem negativações, isso pode acabar por provocar um bloqueio.