# Perguntas que poderiam estar em outra comunidade do Stack Exchange, podem ser feitas nessa comunidade pelo fato de estarem em Português?

Tags: debate

Uma pergunta sobre ubuntu, por exemplo, poderia ser feita na comunidade askubuntu. Porém o usuário teria que fazer a pergunta em Inglês. Nesse caso, a pergunta pode ser feita aqui, ou também está fora do escopo?

Recentemente vi uma pergunta sobre dúvidas com o dual boot. Eu pensei em sinalizar para fechar, pois existe outras comunidades para isso, como por exemplo, server fault e linux&unix. Porém ao clicar na opção "essa resposta pertence a outra comunidade", só apareceu a opção do meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma geral está fora de escopo. Está bem definido em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Algumas pessoas podem querer interpretar que o 3o. item encaixa. Se isto for verdade também pode perguntar sobre cadeira, café, telefone, caneta, etc.

Comment: Por que ao sinalizar que a pergunta pertence a outra comunidade, só aparece a opção meta?

Comment: Porque é a única possibilidade. Uma pergunta em português não pode ir para outros sites da rede, por motivos óbvios, além do nosso meta.

Comment: @Maniero pode ir para o [portuguese.se] ;)

Comment: Muito dificilmente. Se precisar um moderador pode enviar.

Comment: @FagnerFonseca nessa pergunta - https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1241/66203 - é explicado como funciona "a migração" para os outros sites e nessa - https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/264/66203 - é complementada a seção sobre tópicos dentro do escopo do site

Comment: Eu não sabia que tinha uma migração. Pensei que fosse apenas uma sinalização para mostrar o motivo do fechamento da pergunta. Vlw.