# Sugestões de frase pronta para fechamento de perguntas em outros idiomas

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-pronto, razões-fechamento

Em sua [resposta a *Podemos ter opção de migração para o SOzão?*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1253), o Gabe falou da possibilidade de criarmos um novo motivo de fechamento (subtipo de "descontextualizada") para [perguntas que não estejam em português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1031/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-em-um-outro-idioma).

Eu acho que está na hora de termos isso, pois toda semana aparecem algumas perguntas em inglês (ainda não vi nenhuma em outros idiomas). Após esse fechamento muitas perguntas podem ainda ser editadas/traduzidas e reabertas. Outras podem acabar sendo migradas por moderadores.

O que acham? Têm sugestões de frases para usar nesse tipo de fechamento? Eu acho que é bom a frase estar em português e inglês, para orientar quem não fala a nossa língua. Vocês concordam? A frase que escolhermos será postada automaticamente como comentário, e permanece após o fechamento.

Quem tiver mais de uma sugestão, por favor poste-as como respostas independentes, para que possamos votar em cada uma.

Comment: *You're lost, Bobby. Get a grip!*

Comment: Legal, mas tiraram a opção de fechamento Descontextualizado > Off-topic. Não dá para termos os dois? Se tiver que escolher prefiro que deixe o Off topic e tire o motivo de fechamento por estar em outra lingua.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eu apoio e dou minha sugestão, aproveitando a ideia de tradução do Sergio:

> *This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese. It could be reopened if translated.* ~ Esta pergunta está descontextualizada porque não está redigida em Português. Se desejar, faça a tradução e ela poderá ser reaberta.

Versão com sarcasmo:

> *This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese, after all, this is StackOverflow in **Portuguese** (notice the site logo, up there)! Your question could be reopened if translated.* ~ Esta pergunta está descontextualizada porque não está redigida em Português, afinal, aqui é o StackOverflow em **Português** (olha o logo do site lá em cima)! Se desejar, traduza sua questão e ela poderá ser reaberta.

Comment: Gostei do sarcasmo! :)

Comment: A versão com sarcasmo está ótima, acho que *eles* pensam que é só mais um SO com respostas rápidas e mais liberal. +1

Comment: Eu já tinha comentado uma vez: "é muito sem noção", e alguém replicou que o browser pode estar a fazer a tradução... Mas se o sem-noção fala PT, não tem porquê o browser estar configurado pra traduzir essa língua... Enfim, apoiado o sarcasmo!

Comment: Eu gosto da idéia do sarcasmo, mas acho que se for adotada, pode ser reordenada, com o sarcasmo apenas no final (e a informação sobre contexto e reabertura primeiro, ambas as coisas em períodos isolados)

Comment: Prefiro a segunda >:)

Comment: @Bacco Vlw! Tava esquecendo de mudar.

Comment: *This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese. Your question could be reopened if translated. After all, this is StackOverflow **in Portuguese** (notice the site logo, up there).* - Esta pergunta está fora de contexto porque não está redigida em Português. Se desejar, traduza sua questão e ela poderá ser reaberta. Afinal, aqui é o StackOverflow **em Português** (olhe o logo do site lá em cima).

Comment: *This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese, after all, this is StackOverflow in **Portuguese** (notice the site logo, up there)! Your question could be reopened if translated.* ~ Esta pergunta está descontextualizada porque não está redigida em Português, afinal, aqui é o StackOverflow em **Português** (olha o logo do site lá em cima)! Se desejar, traduza sua questão e ela poderá ser reaberta.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not written in Portuguese, after all, this is StackOverflow in **Portuguese** (notice the site logo, up there)! Your question could be reopened if translated. ~ *Esta pergunta está descontextualizada porque não está redigida em Português, afinal, aqui é o StackOverflow em **Português** (olha o logo do site lá em cima)! Se desejar, traduza sua questão e ela poderá ser reaberta.*

Answer (score 4):

Acho bom termos uma opção já feita para esse tipo de perguntas. Aqui fica uma primeira sugestão:

> *This question is in a foreign language for this site, which is for questions in portuguese. The question can be reopened if translated.* | Esta pergunta está numa lingua estrangeira e por isso fora de contexto. Se a pergunta for traduzida para Português, poderá ser reaberta.

ou versão com a parte Inglês em negrito:

> ***This question is in a foreign language for this site, which is for questions in portuguese. The question can be reopened if translated.***  Esta pergunta está numa lingua estrangeira e por isso fora de contexto. Se a pergunta for traduzida para Português, poderá ser reaberta.

Comment: Você acha que a versão em inglês deve vir antes do português? E quebra de linha não poderemos ter, pois o texto será postado como comentário. Podemos usar algum separador, como um pipe ou outro caractere.

Comment: @bfavaretto coloquei primeiro a versão Inglês para o caso do usuário não saber Português. Assim a frase começa numa lingua mais genérica. Tipo "_this message will follow in english_" - Inglês primeiro. Em relação a quebra de linha, podia ser um pipe `|` e também uma das versões estar em __bold__, assim fica mais fácil separar visialmente o conteúdo.

Comment: Também acho que o inglês deve vir primeiro, pois o alvo é o OP. A parte em português é mero complemento para os outros users. E o itálico é adequado e suficiente.

Comment: _This question is in a foreign language, so it's off-topic for this site, which is for questions in portuguese. The question can be reopened if translated._ - Esta pergunta está numa lingua estrangeira e por isso fora de contexto. Se a pergunta for traduzida para Português, poderá ser reaberta.

Comment: @Bacco boa sugestão. Editei o meu texto.