# Sinalizar ou comentar perguntas em inglês?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Sempre tive o costume de comentar perguntas em inglês sugerindo que fossem traduzidas, mas isso até entender/perceber que ao ser fechada como *fora do escopo* é adicionado um comentário informando que ao ser traduzida ela será reaberta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Considerando que a pessoa pode ter criado a pergunta no *SO* e apenas copiado pra o *SOPT*, é interessante apenas comentar e "dar um tempo" pra que a tradução seja feita ou deve-se ir direto na sinalização, já que ela pode ser reativada a qualquer momento?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que fazer com perguntas em um outro idioma?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1031/91)

Comment: Sinalizar e comentar. O comentário sinalizará/informará o AP que algo está errado, permitido que ele corrija antes de, só mais tarde, verificar que a pergunta foi fechada

Answer (score 6):

O comentário pode ser útil porque aparece já, o fechamento pode demorar ou nem ocorrer. É sempre melhor que a pessoa resolva o problema do que fechar.

Lembrando que qualquer pessoa pode traduzir a pergunta e resolver o problema.

Votar para fechar ou sinalizar é válido também, uma coisa não impede a outra.

Comment: fiquei me perguntando esses dias pois vi um comentário em alguma pergunta aqui no **Meta** que dizia algo tipo "só deve-se fechar uma pergunta quando ela não tiver mesmo solução"

Comment: É, isso é uma recomendação, mas se for pensar assim nada deve ser fechado. Tudo tem solução, nem que seja reescrever completamente. E uma tradução não deixa de ser uma reescrita completa. Tem muita confusão de conceitos. Eu acho que o mecanismo, cada funcionário da SE, os moderadores e os usuários, todos individualmente pensam de um jeito diferente. Pra falar a verdade eu acho que deveria rever toda política do site, fazer meio que uma constituição e começar mexer no mecanismo ara atender esses preceitos.Mas parece que estão com a ideia que o caos é bom.Discordo, isto não faz a internet melhor

Answer (score -1):

### Sinalizar e Comentar

Eu penso que a melhor situação no caso do SO<sub>pt</sub> seria seguir a [recomendação do Meta do SO<sub>en</sub>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94659) para sinalizar aos moderadores, porém adicionar um comentário em inglês ou no idioma da pergunta, se possível, para que o usuário possa escolher entre traduzir o conteúdo, manter/cadastrar a pergunta no SO<sub>en</sub>, ou apenas excluir a pergunta.

No caso do SO<sub>en</sub> é compreensivo entender que o idioma inglês é necessário porque o mundo inteiro acessa o site e ficar traduzindo cada pergunta e suas respostas daria muito trabalho.

Eu enxergo algumas situações possíveis:

- O usuário é novo no SO, faz a postagem no SO<sub>en</sub> e como é provável que o SO<sub>en</sub> verifique o idioma ou o IP dele, o direcione para o SO<sub>pt</sub>. Por conta da preguiça, o cidadão copia o cola a questão que já escreveu no SO<sub>en</sub>.
- O usuário é novo no SO<sub>pt</sub> e já conhece o SO<sub>en</sub> e está acostumado a escrever em inglês, escreve/copia a questão em inglês.
- O usuário cai no SO<sub>pt</sub> por engano e acaba colocando a pergunta em inglês ou em outro idioma.

Nessas situações, quando a pergunta é sinalizada e comentada, é possível que o próprio dono da pergunta entenda o que se passa e decida sobre traduzir ou remover. Se ele ignorar ou simplesmente abandonar a pergunta, o moderador pode fazer o encerramento do caso e assim, tanto o moderador não precisa ter uma ação imediata, como o próprio usuário pode ter a chance de fazer a coisa certa.

Uma sugestão de comentário genérico em inglês que poderia colocar na resposta seria:

> Hi! You are in portuguese version of Stack Overflow
>   site. If you speak portugese, please translate your question,
>   otherwise post your question in [Stack Overflow original
>   site](http://stackoverflow.com). Thanks for your visit.